# haskell - String where integer is needed

Tags: string, haskell, error-handling, functional-programming

I have the following code

```
data Ops = Sum Integer | Div Integer | None deriving (Read)

main = do
    ans <- getLine
print $ case read ans of
    Sum n -> sum n
    Div n -> div n
```

I want to display an error message to the user for a wrong input

```
Nothing -> "Error"
```

I understand that I cannot stick in a string here, so how can I possibly implement the error condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better choice would be to use `readMaybe` from `Text.Read`:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

data Ops
    = Sum Integer
    | Div Integer
    | None
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    ans <- getLine
    case readMaybe ans of
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Error"
        Just x  -> print $ handleInput x
    where
        handleInput (Sum n) = sum n
        handleInput (Div n) = div n
```

This lets you separate your error handling from how you handle the input, pulling that out into a pure function away from `IO`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a module like `Text.Read` here is how to define `readMaybe` in terms of just Prelude functions:

```
data Foo = Sum Int Int | Div Int Int deriving (Show,Read)

readMaybe str =
  case reads str of
    [] -> Nothing
    ((a,_):_) -> Just a

main = do
  str <- getLine
  case readMaybe str of
    Nothing         -> putStrLn "bad input"
    Just (Sum a b)  -> print $ a + b
    Just (Div a b)  -> print $ div a b
```